# ¿Cuál es la manera de combinar socket.io con express?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, socket.io

Tengo una duda sobre `socket.io`  al combinarla con express . En la [documentación oficial](https://socket.io/docs/#Using-with-Express) combinan `express`  con el módulo `http` al crear el socket.

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(80);
// WARNING: app.listen(80) will NOT work here!

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Alguien podría ayudarme a entender el por que crean server  del módulo http  utilizando como base el servidor creador a través de express  y el por qué sería una buena práctica.

Actualmente yo uso la siguiente configuración:

```
'use strict'

const config = require('./config')
const express = require('express')
const socket = require('socket.io')
const routes = require('./routes')

const app = express()
app.use(routes)

const server = app.listen(config.puerto, () => console.log(`Escuchando puerto ${config.puerto}`))

const io = socket(server)
```

Donde creo un servidor de express  al cual llamo app , uso `app.use(routes)` para pasarle algunas rutas (en caso que necesite hacer alguna operación como REST API o servir algún estático).

Mi constante server almacena mi servidor corriendo en un puerto (e. g. 6000) y al final creo mi ws con `const io = socket(server)` donde utilizo mi servidor HTTP de express para crear mi socket.

Esto me funciona bien y fácil de configurar.

Mi pregunta es ¿Ustedes consideran esto alguna mala práctica o ven alguna desventaja comparando con el ejemplo de la documentación oficial? ¿Tienen algún consejo?